# Field set labels of contact form not translated

Tags: localisation, language

I just installed and enabled german language, however a few labels are not translated, that is the names of the field groups of the new/edit contact page 'Address', 'Communication Preferences, 'Demographics', 'Tags and Groups'. 'Contact Details' is translated fine.

Also the contact type names 'Individual', 'Household' and 'Organisation' are still in english in the Header 'New Individual/Household/Organisation' which I understand somewhat because these values can be altered in the administration settings. Shouldn't they be multilingual anyway?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SE!  Did you install in English?  If so, see [the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/i18n_l10n/#changing-the-default-civicrm-language-after-installation) and the [fixoptiontranslation](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/fixoptiontranslations) extension.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I don't quite understand why the field set labels were affected by this. If they are configurable where would I have changed them manually?

Comment: Isn't it possible to translate configurable values by storing the key and not the value in the database?